# Image rotation in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new here and this is my first question for an assignment for class.  I am trying to get an image rotation to work in javascript and it is not working for me.  Can someone help? I tried console logging and everything is calling fine.

I have this code within another function for when the end user clicks on a button it triggers the rotation

t = setInterval(scrollImages, 50);

```js
function scrollImages() {
  var coverBarDiv = document.getElementById("coverBar");
  var images = coverBarDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var left = images[i].style.left.substr(0, images[i].style.left.length - 2);
    if (left <= -86) {
      left = 532;
    }
    images[i].style.left = (left - 1) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#coverBar {
  height: 115px;
  left: 182px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 560px;
  width: 440px;
}

#cover img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="coverBar">
  <img src="images/coverMatrix.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 0px;">
  <img src="images/coverDeadRingers.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 88px;">
  <img src="images/coverDrStrangelove.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 176px;">
  <img src="images/coverFuturama.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 264px;">
  <img src="images/coverHolyGrail.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 356px;">
  <img src="images/coverRaisingArizona.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 444px;">
  <img src="images/coverRobotChicken.jpg" width="82" height="115" style="left: 532px;">
</div>
```

Comment: That's a really bad approach. Why do you need js to rotate an image? Why don't you use `transform: rotate(..)` and CSS transitions?

Comment: Do you mean 'scroll left' instead of 'rotate'? The title of your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes scroll left, it is apart of the assignment to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all fine! There was just a typo in CSS selector : `#cover img` should be `#coverBar img`

```js
t = setInterval(scrollImages, 20);

function scrollImages() {
  var coverBarDiv = document.getElementById("coverBar");
  var images = coverBarDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var left = images[i].style.left.substr(0, images[i].style.left.length - 2);
    
    if (left <= -86) {
      left = 532;
    }
    images[i].style.left = (left - 1) + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#coverBar {
  height: 115px;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 440px;
}

#coverBar img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="coverBar">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 0px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 88px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 176px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 264px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 356px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 444px;">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRlq8No0dCjQXEsDTge4boAr22X6m8gVWIYSAkMwj6JYqCC9U" width="82" height="115" style="left: 532px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh snap! Thank you for catching that!